# What is the difference between active reverse polarity and reverse polarity protection in a circuit?

Tags: mosfet, diodes, reverse-polarity

What is the difference between active reverse polarity and reverse polarity protection in an electronics circuit? In battery operated we are giving the reverse polarity protection.

Comment: typically "not active" means there's a diode only allowing current to flow one way, and "active" means a MOSFET only allowing current through if the - is a lower voltage than the +

Answer (score 0):

Active reverse polarity requires power. MOSFET circuits and relays fall under this category.

Passive polarity protection involves passives like diodes.

I prefer to use FETs because they have small power dissipation and a low voltage drop.